# Javascript word frequency bookmarklet omits some letters in the output

Tags: javascript, frequency, bookmarklet, cpu-word

I could not find a word frequency extension for Chrome which lists the number of times a word was used on a page (I needed a list of at least 100 results arranged by frequency of usage), so I resorted to copying a javascript bookmarklet and tweaking it a little to filter out common words.

However, both the original code and the modded code output a list which omits the first letter of some words, for example "roperty" instead of "property", "ubversion" instead of "subversion", etc. What could be causing this?

Here is a link to the original code: https://gist.github.com/RonnyO/3004194

Here is the code after I tweaked it a little:

```
javascript: (function () {
            var settings = {
                           listLength: 100,
                           ignore: ['the', 'be', 'to', 'of', 'and', 'in', 'that', 'have', 'it', 'for', 'not', 'on', 'with', 'he', 'as', 'you', 'do', 'at', 'this', 'but', 'his', 'by', 'from', 'they', 'we', 'say', 'her', 'she', 'or', 'an', 'will', 'my', 'one', 'all', 'would', 'there', 'their', 'what', 'so', 'up', 'out', 'if', 'about', 'who', 'get', 'which', 'go', 'me', 'when', 'make', 'can', 'like', 'time', 'no', 'just', 'him', 'know', 'fake', 'people', 'into', 'year', 'your', 'good', 'some', 'could', 'them', 'see', 'other', 'than', 'then', 'now', 'look', 'only', 'come', 'its', 'over', 'think', 'also', 'back', 'after', 'use', 'two', 'how', 'our', 'work', 'first', 'well', 'way', 'even', 'new', 'want', 'because', 'any', 'these', 'give', 'day', 'most', 'us']
                    },
                    w, s;
            function getBodyText() {
                    var doc = document,
                            body = doc.body,
                            selection, range, bodyText;
            if (body.createTextRange) {
                            return body.createTextRange().text;
            } else if (getSelection) {
                            selection = getSelection();
                            range = doc.createRange();
                            range.selectNodeContents(body);
                            selection.addRange(range);
                            bodyText = selection.toString();
                            selection.removeAllRanges();
                            return bodyText;
            }
     }

     var punctuation = /[\/\.\*\+\+\?\|\(\)\[\]\{\}\^\\,:;-`~!@#$%&_]+/g;
     var words = getBodyText().trim().replace(punctuation, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' '),
               count = {},
               sorted = [];

    for (w in words) {if (words.hasOwnProperty(w) && settings.ignore.indexOf(words[w]) == -1) {
        var word = words[w];
        count[word] = count[word] ? count[word] + 1 : 1;
    }
}

for (w in count) if (count.hasOwnProperty(w)) {
    sorted.push([w, count[w]]);
}

s = sorted.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
});

var output = '<title>word frequency</title><ul style="direction: ltr; text-align: left; font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 130%;">';
for (s in sorted.slice(0, settings.listLength)) {
    var c = sorted[s];
    output += '<li>' + c[1] + ': ' + c[0] + '</li>';
}
output += '</ul>';

with(open().document){
    write(output);
    close();
}
})();
```

Sorry for the terrible indenting..

Comment: Can you post the link to the page you ran this on?

Comment: I ran it on the very webpage the code originates from (https://gist.github.com/RonnyO/3004194), but it seems like the problem is in the code. The first letter on some words is omitted from the output regardless of which website I run the script on.

Or do you suspect it's some sort of font / text format issue?

Comment: Your `punctuation` regex includes the range `;-\``. This range includes all the capital letters. I suspect this is not what you meant.

Comment: By "font / text format issue" I was referring to the code's inability to process website texts properly, and seeing a specific word as 2 different words, e.g. seeing the word overflow as both "overflow" and "verflow" and listing it twice in the output. Here's a link to the output: http://i.imgur.com/VZaePkn.png?1

Be aware I have 0 knowledge in javascript. Tried tweaking the range you provided with no results other than the code refusing to work.

Comment: @lestrange Yes, if the word appears in the page as both `overflow` and as `Overflow`, your regex will strip the initial capital letter from the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the punctuation to escape the hyphen.

```
var punctuation = /[\/\.\*\+\+\?\|\(\)\[\]\{\}\^\\,:;\-`~!@#$%&_]+/g;
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! This has fixed the code wonderfully. Any ideas on how to transform all the output into lower-case?

Comment: Sure, try changing
    var word = words[w];
to
   var word = words[w].toLowerCase();

Comment: Thank you once more, and everyone else who helped! You have saved me tremendous amounts of time! I hope this code will be as useful to others as well.